# mergeData error when using Vue Grid Layout?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am using Vue and Vue Grid Layout to make a dashboard application. When the user connects to the application with his account, his widgets are retrieved from a MongoDB database and displayed on the Home page with vue grid layout.

The error doesn't occur on first load, but always occurs when the user navigates through an other page (using Vue router) like his profile or settings, and then returns to the Home Page. Vue router doesn't seem to be the problem as the URL changes.

The error seems to be from Vue Grid Layout since when i comment the code the error doesn't appear.

Here is the exact error : [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRKSa.png)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you think that's a bug in the library, that would be wise to provide them a reproduction process and post an issue on their github.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug in the library, i've included it in my project in march and haven't got any issue until last week and no updates were released. The error is mine, I just can't seem to figure out where it comes from.

Comment: That's almost impossible to help you without a small reproduction of the code leading to this error anyway.

Comment: That's what I thought too but I would have to reproduce the entire application... Thanks anyway !